# How do I plot an inequality containing absolute values?

Tags: maple

Is it possible to plot $|x|+|y|<=1$ directly in maple?
I have looked at `inequal()` but can't find any examples with absolute values and can't get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
plots:-inequal(abs(x)+abs(y)<=1,x=-2..2,y=-2..2);
```

[image]

```
plots:-implicitplot(abs(x)+abs(y)<=1,x=-2..2,y=-2..2,
                    gridrefine=1,filledregions,
                    view=[-2..2,-2..2]);
```

[image]